# Combining two macros in a composite fashion

Tags: macros, expansion

In this example, there are two macros: 1) `\removefinalpoints` to remove any number of final points `.` in the its parameter; and 2) `\capitalizekeywords` a macro to capitalize every word in a sequence of keywords, separated by `\sep` which is defined by `\def\sep{\unskip. }`. I want to capitalize the keywords and then remove the last (multiple) final points, so that I would get the intended list of keywords ending with just one final point. In the code below I've commented the line that words, but does not remove the final point.

```
\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\makeatletter 
\def\sep{\unskip. }%
\newcommand{\capitalizekeywords}[2][\sep]{%
  \def\dolist##1{\expandafter\@dolist##1#1\@eol}%
  \def\@dolist##1#1##2\@eol{%
    \begingroup\setbox0=\hbox{##1\unskip}\ifdim\wd0=0pt\endgroup\else\endgroup\ignorespaces\makefirstuc{##1}\unskip\sep\fi%
    \ifx\@eol##2\@eol\else\@dolist##2\@eol\fi}%
  \dolist{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\removefinalpoints}[1]{%
  \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{%
    \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\preresult]%
    \def\result{\removefinalpoints\preresult}%
  }{\def\result{#1}}{\result}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{\z@}%
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{%
   %\emph{keywords: }\capitalizekeywords{#1}\unskip.\par
   \emph{keywords: }\removefinalpoints{\capitalizekeywords{#1}}\unskip.\par
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\keywords{one \sep two \sep three.}
\keywords{one \sep two \sep three}
\removefinalpoints{test 123.}\par
\removefinalpoints{test 123..}

\end{document}
```

I guess it have to do with `\expandafter`, but I've tried using it with no success.

Comment: Actually, because `\capitalizekeywords` contains `\def`initions, it cannot be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `expl3`.

The various items are collected ignoring leading and trailing spaces. Then the items are transformed by applying `\text_titlecase:n`, which capitalizes the first letter. Next the whole list is delivered by placing a comma and a space (denoted in the code by `~`, because we're in the `expl3` programming environment) between them, and a trailing period. Then multiple periods are reduced to one and the final result is delivered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\keywords}{m}
 {
  \par\noindent
  \emph{Keywords:~}
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \sep } { #1 }
  \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \text_titlecase:n { ##1 } }
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { .~ }. }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { \.+ } { \. } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\keywords{one \sep two. \sep three.}

\keywords{one \sep two \sep three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @egreg. I've never user ```expl3```, but I guess might be also possible using ```LaTeX2e```.